# React Native Animated vs Reanimated which one is more performant?

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated

I've used Animated so far, but I can't use some values like `height` without making `useNativeDriver: false`. That's why I want to use Reanimated. So, React Native `Animated` vs `Reanimated` which one is more performant?

Answer (score 2):

both are good:

- reanimated has many ready-to-use configurations and you don't have to do much if you want a simple animation. but it is a third-party library, so you have to keep it updated, especially when a new version of react native is released.
- Animated is built in with react native, so you don't have to maintain it or something like that, and its pretty nice too.
  PS : when reanimated 2.0 upgraded to 3.0, they made too many breaking changes which I had the change the code of my animations everywhere in my project, so it was a week changing just the animations. good luck!